# Typescript: How do define keys of an object by inference?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to define the keys of the nested object without typing it out. How can I get typescript to only accept the keys "itemA" and "itemB" without typing it out (because in practice there are more than 2 keys)?

```
// I don't want the key to be any string. It should be whatever is in the object so `itemA | itemB`.
// I also DO NOT want to define all keys myself since it's much longer than in this example
interface IMyObject {
    bucket1: Record<string, string>;
}

const myObject:IMyObject = {
    bucket1: {
        itemA: "itemA",
        itemB: "itemB",
    },
}

// This should be invalid
const itemC = myObject.bucket1.itemC;
```

Comment: So you just need the keys in `bucket1` and `bucket2` to be string ? Or you need something that's more specific ?

Comment: @Psidom nah the keys can't just be strings. They need to be specifically defined using `keyof typeof myObject.bucket1` or with generics somehow. Just like at the bottom where I have bucket1Props

Comment: Doesn't `type IBuckets = typeof objectWithTwoBucketsOnly;` work for you in that case ?

Comment: @Psidom I'm not seeing how that would work. I want to define the object before I declare it. What I know is that this object will have two keys: `bucket1: {}` and `bucket2: {}` and within each bucket there is a looong unique list of keys. And the keys need to be explicitly defined

Comment: @Psidom I think the solution is something like `interface IBuckets<Type> {bucket1: [key: keyof typeof Type<bucket1>]: string}, bucket2: [key: keyof typeof Type<bucket2>]: string},` or something like that, but I don't fully understand the syntax currently

Comment: Sure then I think the way to do it is to explicitly list out all the keys in the type definition. I don't think generics will help here. No generics can automatically figure out what keys you have in an object.

Comment: The issue here is you are trying to define the type from the object and also use the type to annotate the object. You have a circular dependency here. You must have at least one explicitly defined without relying on the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237541/discussion-between-wongz-and-psidom).

Comment: You don't have enough detail. Your sample object shows what is acceptable, but we need examples of what would not be acceptable. As-is, this question is way too vague to offer any kind of meaningful answer (without just guessing)

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica I rewrote the example to try to clarify the question. We know there is a "solid" and "outline" nested object. And we want to explicitly define the color names inside each.

Comment: Your example still does not contain enough detail. Based on what you have shared so far, `interface ISolid { [key: string]: string; }` meets your requirements. I'm guessing this is not what you are looking for, but I don't know what would meet your _actual_ requirements.

Comment: For example, what is `Type.solid`? And why did you think you needed generics in the first place? What is an example of a data structure that would fail? Is `const styles:IStyles = { solid: { fizzbang: "itemA", } } };` valid?

Comment: My lack of understanding of TS is probably confusing the issue. I just want to define the keys of the items inside outline and solid without typing them out explicitly because it's long. `Type.solid` is me trying to define the keys of the items inside the solid object. I may not need generics. Your example would be valid if it had an `outline:{}` object too and IStyles was used to define your object. It would be invalid if you tried to access my object and did `const fizzbang = styles.solid.fizzbang` because fizzbang doesn't exist on my object. You'd be limited to the colors in my orig object

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica I simplified the example a bit. Would you have any thoughts on how to solve the issue now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
// I don't want the key to be any string. It should be whatever is in the object so `itemA | itemB`.
// I also DO NOT want to define all keys myself since it's much longer than in this example
interface IMyObject<T> {
    bucket1: Record<keyof T, string>;
}

const bucket = {
        itemA: "itemA",
        itemB: "itemB",
    }
    
const myObject:IMyObject<typeof bucket> = {
    bucket1: bucket,
}

// This should be invalid
const itemC = myObject.bucket1.itemC;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Could you also provide an option if I wanted the bucket to not to be separated out? That is, if `myObject` was fully intact. Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps all you need is a constructor function that would takes a bucket of type Record<string, string> and returns IMyObject

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to define a type while also conforming to a broader type at the same time, so I am not sure if this is possible, unless you use a function that would accept bucket and return IMyObject

Comment: Sounds good. Your answer with the code above breaking it down into parts, and stating that it's probably not possible unless I create a function or constructor is a sufficiently complete answer for me. Thanks.

Comment: People have been asking for such feature, you can upvote or describe your case in the following issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question **as asked**, you do not need any explicit types at all. TypeScript will infer the type information based on the object literal:

```
const myObject = {
    bucket1: {
        itemA: "itemA",
        itemB: "itemB",
    },
}

// This is invalid
const itemC = myObject.bucket1.itemC;
```

If your situation is more complex, then please provide additional details to help us understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess author wants to make sure that nested objects are all records of strings

Comment: @ZZB - I would love to see that specification in the question itself, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Appreciate the response fellas. Yes, the issue is that elsewhere I use `keyof typeof myObject.bucket1` so the object keys (and in my specific project the values too) cannot be of type string but instead I need it to be defined. I mentioned here that the keys need to be defined in the question and the comments. Overall am looking for what @ZZB had but even more interested if there's a way to keep the original object in tact.